# what is the error of this simple code block?

Tags: c, file

This the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct num{
    int a[5];
};

int main(){
    struct num n;
    n.a[0]=56;

    FILE * fp=fopen("saman.txt","w+");

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("error");
        exit(0);
    }

    fwrite(&n,sizeof(n),1,fp);  
    fread(&n,sizeof(n),1,fp);   
    printf("%i",n.a[0]);
}
```

output is 0,but it should be 56,shoudn't it?
can u please help me?

Comment: This is so readable. Prolly you have to rewind back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: [rewind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/).

Comment: I don't think so, i am getting 56.

Answer (score 4):

When you write the structure, the position pointer of the file is increased. When you try to read, it will try to read from the current position, but it's now at the end of the file so you don't read anything.

You should check the return value of `fread` to see if it actually succeeded.

---

After checking the C specification (C11) section 7.21.8.1 (titled "The fread function") it doesn't actually say anywhere what should happen to the data when there is an error, so I would say that the state of the data you attempt to read into is undefined and can be anything.

Comment: If `fread` failed, shouldn't `n.a[0]` retain its old value of 56?

Comment: @interjay Just added a note about that.

Comment: Aren't read and write pointers different ? I mean, fwrite will use write pointer and fread should use the read pointer.

Comment: @VivekS C stdio files only have one pointer, used for both reading and writing.